# WiFi repeater and hotspot has no Internet access on the connected devices

Tags: windows-7, repeater, virtual-wifi

Regardless of whether I use a third-party application like Connectify, or manually add a repeater, there is no Internet access on connected devices.

I created a WiFi repeater hosted network with the name mywifi.  The Internet works fine at first when the device is connected.  After 30-40 seconds, Internet access is lost but the WiFi signals are there.  When I turn off that device's WiFi and turn it on again, it doesn't reconnect to mywifi, meaning no WiFi signals.

It will connect when I restart the laptop and then turn it on again and restart the repeater.  But it has the same issue: just 30-40 seconds of Internet access.

My network card used to work fine.  Then my laptop had some hard disk issue and I had to replace the hard disk.  I did a clean install of Windows 7 on the new hard disk (I was also using Windows 7 before).  I downloaded third-party apps for the repeater and that is causing this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to use Windows as the repeater? That won't work unless you use something like Internet Connection Sharing. You can't just bridge to a WiFi client connection, that will not work for more than one device at a time.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Answer (score 0):

No i also tried 3rd party applications too.
anyways i found the issue. I updated my network drivers via driverMax and its all good now

if anyone else got same issue than download driverMax or anyother driver updater software and update drivers. It solved issue for me